# how to bind loaded xml in xul tree

Tags: javascript, xml, tree, xul, graphic

I use xul inteface to load an xml file and then I want to display it's graphical tree using XUL trees but I don't know how to do it. please could anyone told me how to implement it, or is there any other tool that allows me to generate th graphical tree of my xml file? 
 thank you

Comment: Binding is doable i forgot how but in your other topic i gave some sources check that out :) i thought binding was done via rdf but im not sure